# Grails unit tests and cobertura xml file conflict (bug?)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, cobertura

To generate xml report from all unit tests in grails (2.1) u will only need tu run `grails test-app`. This command creates `\target\test-reports\TESTS-TestSuites.xml` file. I installed Cobertura plugin for coverage reports. By default cobertura creates html report, but I need xml report for jenkins. To get XML file for cobertura u must use `-xml` option, so the full command looks like: `test-app -coverage -xml`.
After executing this command, file `TESTS-TestSuites.xml` was not created and as far as I checked it, this `-xml` option for cobertura interfere with `test-app` command.

How to run all tests and generate both xml files for unit tests and cobertura coverage? Is this a bug?

Comment: The two command-line options shouldn't conflict. Have you tried putting the `coverage { xml=true }` block into your `BuildConfig`? Then you should be able to just run `grails test-app` and it will default to XML.

Comment: Putting this option to config file resolved my problem. Thanks! I think there is still a problem with using this grails command.